# How to show disk usage of a package including dependencies?

Tags: package-management

I'm using aptitude as package manager. If one marks packages for removal it calculates the changing in disk usage, i.e. how much space is freed by removing that package and its automatically installed, otherwise unused dependencies.

Is there a way (not necessarily within aptitude) to get this number for, say, all packages marked manually installed?

Comment: Does [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62290/how-do-i-list-installed-software-with-the-installed-size) help, or no? I guess that doesn't show all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the apt-get from the command line it will tell you the total disk usage before you confirm the install.

$ sudo apt-get install php5
..
..
..
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,459 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?