# My machine's information

Tags: package-management, versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list all installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)
>   [How do I list installed software with the installed size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62290/how-do-i-list-installed-software-with-the-installed-size)

is there a way to know what are the packages installed on my machine, detailed information, like each software and its version? Like to know if I have qt installed and what version, or gcc and what version.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list installed software with the installed size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62290/how-do-i-list-installed-software-with-the-installed-size) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a terminal, you can do a

```
dpkg --list
```

to get an overview of all installed packages including their version numbers. Since this generates usually a long output, you might consider to do

```
dpkg --list | less
```

or

```
dpkg --list | grep qt
```

Comment: What does it mean to have ri or ii at the beginning of each line?

Comment: These are status flags. The first letter is the desired installation status, the second says something about the de-facto installation status. "ri" means it is currently installed, but is about to be removed, "ii" means it was successfully installed. "ri" is kinda strange though - was there a problem with your last attempt to remove a package? If I remove a package, it usually shows as "rc": removed, configuration files left on the system.

Comment: no, actaully i tried to remove the gcc-4.6 becuae i installed gcc-4.7, i think thats why i'm having ri, but it didnt get removed becuase other softwares like gnat-4.6 depends on it, so is it okay if i leave it like this or should i fix it?

Comment: You can leave it like that. It won't do any harm other than having multiple versions of gcc around.

Answer (score 1):

**To List all packages installed**

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

**To get details about particular package version use**

- `dpkg -l <package_name>`

  or
- `apt-cache policy <package_name>`

Example:

```
$ dpkg -l perl
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  perl           5.14.2-13    i386         Larry Wall's Practical Extraction
$ 


$ apt-cache policy perl
perl:
  Installed: 5.14.2-13
  Candidate: 5.14.2-13
  Version table:
 *** 5.14.2-13 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$
```

**To show the version along with the installed package**. use

```
apt-show-versions
```

If apt-show-versions is not installed use `sudo apt-get install apt-show-versions`